# What's cm:subscribable made for?

Tags: alfresco

In the original `contentModel.xml` file, I see there is an aspect called `cm:subscribable` :

```
  <aspect name="cm:subscribable">
     <associations>
        <association name="cm:subscribedBy">
           <source>
              <mandatory>false</mandatory>
              <many>true</many>
           </source>
           <target>
              <class>cm:person</class>
              <mandatory>false</mandatory>
              <many>true</many>
           </target>
        </association>
     </associations>
  </aspect>
```

I would like to know what it is made for/used to, since I didn't found enough information [in the documentation](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/references/dev-extension-points-content-model-define-and-deploy.html).
Is there an existing function in Alfresco which uses it, or this is just an aspect made "in case" someone wants to developp a suscribable functionnality ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging a little, it looks like it is used when we subscribe/follow an user in share.

Watching the [Subscription service](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/org/alfresco/service/cmr/subscriptions/SubscriptionService.html) and the existing webscripts helped me to understand that.